# What do you call this plastic paneling on the outside of garage?

Tags: garage, siding, plastic

My garage has the white plastic paneling that looks like wood.

Some of it broke off during a storm and I need to replace it. I'm having some trouble finding it online because I don't know what you call it. It snaps on.

[image]

I have been calling it plastic paneling and plastic siding in my searches, but that brings up unrelated products only so far.

**update:** is it "cladding"? I still haven't found an exact match but now I am thinking that's the general term for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is vinyl siding, available at big box stores. It will come in different sizes, double 4 or double 5, counting the inches between each horizontal bump. Some comes in double 4 1/2". Double means, there are 2 horizontal lines for each piece of siding.  There are other sizes available too, along with styles of the face that is created in the bending process.

Comment: Thanks. Is this different from cladding?

Comment: Cladding is another name for siding, that term is used for other types of siding as well